# Python version for mod_wsgi

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

how can I change the default version mod_wsgi uses?

I am using Debian 5 with Apache 2.

Answer (score 7):

Look for `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so*`, at least on ubuntu I have:

```
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so -> mod_wsgi.so-2.6
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so-2.5
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so-2.6
```

If you change the symlink, you change the default mod_wsgi.

An alternative is to look in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/wsgi.load`, for me that's just one line:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

If you point that at one of those `mod_wsgi.so-2.x` files, you've changed the default version.

Answer (score 2):

When you say different version you mean Python 2.5 vs 2.6, then you must install mod_wsgi package binary compiled against Python 2.5, or compile mod_wsgi from source code yourself against the Python 2.5 version. See notes about --with-python option in:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide#Configuring_The_Source_Code

Answer (score 0):

you should look into using virtualenv. I think that is what you are looking for

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments

Comment: Is it possible to create virtualenv with higher Python version than system has?

Comment: yes.. i do it for hosting Django apps on redhat el 5 that only has 2.4.. I run 2.6 in virtualenv. You just have to install it on the system as an option

Comment: Virtual environments can only be used for the same version of Python as mod_wsgi was compiled for. You cannot have mod_wsgi compiled against Python 2.4 and then create a virtual environment for Python 2.6 and point mod_wsgi at it. Python 2.4 will still be what actually runs. In the mean time you are potentially mixing Python code/extension modules from a different version of Python, which can cause all manner of problems or crashes.